# What exactly is a "estómago cerrado"?

Tags: locuciones

I heard the expression "Tengo el estómago cerrado" when people are asked if they want something to eat but decline.

I understand it literally means "closed stomach", but what exactly is meant by this? Is this just a indirect way of saying "I'm not hungry" or "I have no appetite", or do they actually mean some (minor) medical issue like an upset stomach? How is this expression used in practice?

I don't find much on the internet, only help pages like [this one](https://salud.facilisimo.com/d/remedios-para-aliviar-los-nervios-y-abrir-el-estomago-cerrado_2225371.html) that are a bit vague; they talk about being nervous. But I can't quite make sense of this; the last time I heard it in the speaker wasn't nervous or sick or anything, it just seemed a way for him to say "I don't want to eat right now".

(If relevant, this was Antonio in the bar "La Parra", in the series "Servir y proteger" which is set in Madrid; after he ordered a coffee Maria asked him if he also wanted to eat something.)

Edit: I thought I had heard "*un* estómago" but this was likely wrong as the expression is "tengo *el* estómago cerrado" (thanks to @Gorpik for correcting me).

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "Tengo *el* estómago cerrado"? We would not say *un* in this case, because we have only one stomach.

Comment: @Gorpik Thanks, you're probably right. I thought it was "un" but it's really hard to remember an expression precisely when you only hear it in a conversation and not read it. It was all fast and a bit blurred anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If somebody *tiene el estómago cerrado*, it means that they don't have an appetite, but for reasons other than not being hungry, like being nervous, etc.

In English, we also say things like "my stomach is in knots", which conveys the same meaning with a similar metafor (although the English expression doesn't reference appetite specifically). In both languages, context will tell you exactly *why* the person feels this way.

***Tengo el estómago cerrado*** *desde ayer cuando me peleé con mi amigo* = **My stomach has been in knots** ever since I fought with my friend yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Las causas pueden ser diversas;

Por enfermedad se llama *gastroparesis* que es una enfermedad que afecta al movimiento espontáneo normal de los músculos *motilidad* del estómago, ya que las contracciones musculares fuertes impulsan los alimentos por el tubo digestivo.

Si los nervios gástricos se desequilibran pueden aparecer síntomas desagradables como consecuencia:
Sensación de pesadez y/o hinchazón estomacal.
Náuseas.
Dolor de estómago.
Gases o flatulencias.
Ardor.

De forma popular se dice cuando una a una persona "se le cierra el estómago" cuando esta preocupada por algún motivo que pueden ser Disgustos, preocupaciones, pensamientos negativos, el estrés... y que en muchas ocasiones quitan el apetito. Es igualmente correcto decir “nudo en el estómago", por la contracción del diafragma.

Espero que te ayude. Saludos.

Diego M.